# DynamoDB - Can you get the equivalent of @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey on primary key when creating a table through AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, uuid, amazon-dynamodb, auto-generate

Although the AWS Java SDK provides a way to set a primary index on a table to be unique/auto-generated, I don't see a way to do this through AWS console.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I think I was thinking about this incorrectly.  I think the annotation is a feature of the dynamo db ORM in the aws java sdk, as is not based on a property of the table itself, so I'm thinking my question doesn't make sense.

I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is as far as delete/comment/answer your own question in this scenario; but I thought maybe it would be helpful to someone else, so I didn't delete it.

Comment: I would say it is probably best to improve this as an answer. If you had this question, it is likely that somebody else probably thought of it too. The annotation **is** a feature of the mapper, and looking through the source code of the AWS SDK will tell you how it is done (look at the `DynamoDBMapper.getAutoGeneratedKeyAttributeValue` method)